# What is the difference between ofInt, ofFloat, and ofObject for ObjectAnimator?

Tags: java, android

I've been struggling to understand what is the difference between `ofFloat, ofInt,` and `ofObject` for sometime. Part my struggle is that I don't know when to use each one. I tried using `ofInt` for translationY property and it won't work. However, whenever I use `ofFloat` the animation works perfectly. I am not so sure why this is the case.

1) I would like to know why `ofInt` and `ofFloat` makes such a big difference in the uses when animating the translationY property to the point where one work and the other doesn't.

2) I would like to know when to use these different methods (`ofFloat, ofInt, and ofObject`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You choose the version of the method that matches the underlying datatype for the property you want to animate.  So if you look at [setTranslationX()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTranslationX%28float%29), you'll see that it accepts a float.  That means you choose ofFloat() for animating the value.  As you saw, that works fine.

Comment: Hey this is the second time you answer one of my question and I appreciated it a lot. I just want to clarify on how object animator works. So when I use ofFloat for instance, the ofFloat method calls the setTranslationX() method and feed it a specifies float value as a parameter and the setTranslationX() changes the object position. Am I correct in this assumption?

Comment: Yes, as the animator changes the targeted value over time, it will make a change to the underlying property. It turns out that for translation, the animator will call exactly that method to make changes.  But I'm not sure it's a good idea to *depend* on that specific method being called.  It's an implementation detail and could change later.